# imagebutton: src should fit height but not lenght

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I want my big picture to fit the whole screen, but also it should overlap at the width.

have tried this:

```
   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/gameover"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/farmlvl1"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
       android:visibility="visible" />
```

have a look at the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/gameover"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/farmlvl1"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:visibility="visible" />
```

You also need `adjustViewBounds` because else it sometimes wouldn't fit the height.

Comment: @EmanuelGraf No problem. If you think this is the correct answer you should mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin van Mierlo. I've marked your answer as correct. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please concider to upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/farmlvl1"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
   android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RelativeLayout
2. Check with this code:

   ```
     android:id="@+id/gameover"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:scaleType="matrix"
     android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
     android:visibility="visible" />
   ```